# How expensive is access to database? How often do we access to it?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-connection

I'm about to write an application for Android, and it will use Mysql.
I know that access to DB is really expensive in terms of time, and would like to know how often do applications like instant messaging, online gaming access to databases?
For example in a game, we would like to save the positions of a player in the world, when he's moving all the time.

Is the database access actually not expensive, and there is a way to be connected to it all the time and just do request that are actually not expensive?

Or is IT really expensive in anyway, and there are techniques to access to it for example every X interval of time, and saving it locally in the meantime?

I Know that my question is really general, and it depends always on what we need and want.
My question came out because i made a really simple login application that connects and does 1 request to database, and it takes 1 second (a lot!!) to get the result, so how online applications can be so fast?

Thank you

Comment: How often you access a database depends entirely on your application (or to a certain extend the libraries you use), makes sense, right?

Comment: hey, thanks for your comment, yes it does depend on it entirely. but my question is still interesting to me, how do we store the data in a game? is it fast enough do access all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering this I would recommend simulating the process as much as possible, benchmarking and you can work towards the best solution for your use case.

e.g. If I have an application submitting data to a database simulate the submission so I can easily run multiple submissions at the same time and see what the bottle neck is...and see how it compares when I using caching, replication, indexes, etc.

Also reading company blogs can be helpful as they often share [success stories](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value) that support the usage of a particular approach

### How expensive is access to database?

Accessing a database **can** be a pretty quick operation

```
SELECT 1;    // 0.005 Secs :D
```

However there are situations that can lead to poor performance (slow reads, writes and updates) but there are some relatively simple ways to combat this

- [Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

> The best way to improve the performance of SELECT operations is to
>   create indexes on one or more of the columns that are tested in the
>   query. The index entries act like pointers to the table rows, allowing
>   the query to quickly determine which rows match a condition in the
>   WHERE clause, and retrieve the other column values for those rows.

- [Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

> spreading the load among multiple slaves to improve performance. In
>   this environment, all writes and updates must take place on the master
>   server. Reads, however, may take place on one or more slaves. This
>   model can improve the performance of writes (since the master is
>   dedicated to updates), while dramatically increasing read speed across
>   an increasing number of slaves.

### How often do we access to it?

If you are **solely** using a database you will access it every time you n position and every time you need to find out their position.

This is where you would explore options to prevent accessing the database.

1. Memory caches such as redis or memcache
2. Replication - Only read from slaves

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your design and requirement.

1) Most of the applications manage Connection Pools to minimize the initialization time.

2) Most of the ORM frameworks have external Cache to improve the reading performance. So if you do heavy data reading in your application then don't worry about storing it in locally. The Cache will be effective in this case.

3) When you store locally either in File (or) some format, then it will also add extra performance delay.

4) If you keep the data in primary memory, then obviously `Game` performance would be better. That's why `Gamers` prefer high end graphics card, and huge RAM.

Answer (score 1):

For most databases there is the option of batch insertions. Obviously even a small overhead will accumulate if you have to many connections over time. And performing single insertions will have a greater overhead than on batch. The only issue is how often?.... And you should test how often you wan't to insert and how much information you should store locally before doing a batch insertion.